Difference between `across(all_of())` and `!!`
Starting from a data.frame indf and colname being one of its columns, I want to build another dataframe outdf with 2 columns: the first, called colname, containes the unique values of indf$colname, while the second, called n, contains the number of duplicates in indf$colname (the original included, so sum(duplicated())+1).
colname should be dynamically specified.
After some research and trial and error, it looks like the way to do this is:
indf <- data.frame(a=c("A","A","B"), b=c(1,2,3))
colname = "a"
outdf <- indf %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(colname))) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  select(!!colname, n)

I would like to know why group_by requires across(all_of(colname)) to process the dynamically defined column name, while with select I have to unquote using !!.
If I use across(all_of()) in select I get this error:
Error in `select()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(all_of(colname))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`,
  `filter()`, and `group_by()`.

While if I use !! in group_by it creates a new column named "a" (double quotes included).
EDIT:
The !! doesn't work inside arrange as well.
# This doesn't work
outdf %>%
  arrange(desc(!!colname))

Instead you need across(all_of()):
outdf %>%
  arrange(desc(across(all_of(colname))))


group_by( !!sym(colname) ) also works.

The function all_of is a selection helper function, like matches and contains. Under the hood, it just converts your column name to a numerical column index. However, as of tidyselect v1.2.0, the selection helpers have to be used inside a selecting context (see ?`faq-selection-context`).
This means that the selection helpers can be used directly inside select without being wrapped in across, since this is already a selection context.
With other verbs such as mutate and group_by, these do not constitute a selection context, and the function across is required to convert the column indices into inputs appropriate for those functions.
Simply use select(all_of(colname)) without the across:
library(dplyr)

indf    <- data.frame(a = c("A", "A", "B"), b = c(1, 2, 3))
colname <- "a"

indf %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(colname))) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  select(all_of(colname), n)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   a [2]
#>   a         n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 A         2
#> 2 A         2
#> 3 B         1


and why !! doesn't work inside group_by? It doesn't work inside arrange as well

@robertspierre because group_by(!!colname) evaluates to group_by("a"), not group_by(a). That's because colname is a character string, not a symbol. You would need something like group_by(!!str2lang(colname)) to get that to work. It only works inside select because select can take character strings as arguments too (indf %>% select("a") will select column a). group_by does not take character strings as a grouping argument.

That looks way too more complicated and bloated than it should be, with more exceptions than rules

@robertspierre in some ways you are making it more complicated than it needs to be by trying to use tools in places where they aren't designed to be used. If you have your columns stored as a character string, use the selecting functions indf %>% group_by(across(all_of(colname))) %>% select(all_of(colname)). Tidyverse uses non-standard evaluation to make it super simple to directly select or group by column names directly. Once you start storing column names as characters you are doing something unusual that requires work-arounds and might be better done outside tidyverse.

I need to write a generic function that achieves this whatever the dataframe and  the column name

@robertspierre so why not use the code in my answer? You don't need the !! operator here.
